# Definition of Lebesgue integration: $sup$ over set of what excatly?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Definition from wikipedia: (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration, non negative integration)
$$sup\{\sum_k a_k1_{A_k}\leq f\}$$
So is this a supreme over all partitions of the codomain and also the coefficients of the simple functions? i.e. $$\sup_{\{a_k\}\in R, A_k\subset D}\{\sum_k a_k1_{A_k}\leq f\}$$

Answer (score 2):

The supremum is over the set of non-negative simple functions.

Comment: Which means all partition of the real line and also real coefficients?

Comment: Not exactly. The subsets defining a simple functions have to be measurable, this is not the case in general if you take some partition of the real line. The coefficients have to be non-negative. Moreover, a simple function does not have a unique decomposition.